# indexing form elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching around and all the answers I've seen will use something along the lines of `$('form :input')$` to get all of the inputs. But I already have a reference to the form using `$("form").submit()` and I just need to grab a specific input field from the fieldname. I'm unsure of how to use `$(this)` with additional selectors to get the forms specific elements

So, how would I go about doing that.

Example of the bit of code I need to workout.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var form = $(this)
    var form_errors = array_of_errors
    for(var fieldname in form_errors){
        var errors = form_errors[fieldname]
        var field = \\how to get this
        \\ Something like $(form, 'input[name='+fieldname+']') maybe?
    }
});
```

Comment: It's `$('input[name='+fieldname+']', form)` the correct syntax. [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Comment: `$(":input", form)` retrives all input elements

Comment: Okay, got it working I needed to remove the `$` on `var form = $(this)` on the initial function part below `.submit()`. So `var form = this` worked. And I had it backwards. Post as solution?

Comment: try this `$('input[name="'+fieldname+'"]', form)` if you have special chars in you name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `$(selector, context)`

jQuery selectors can have a second argument, used to define their context.

```
$(`input[name=${fieldname}]`, form);
```

will do the trick.

This means that your selector will look only inside the element you have passed as context.

Documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

---

### `$(context).find(selector)`

An alternative could be to use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) in conjunction with the context:

```
$(form).find(`input[name=${fieldname}]`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var $form       = $(this),             // good naming practice to use $ to signify jQuery object
        form_errors = validateForm(this);  // semi-colon

    var fields = Object.keys( form_errors );
    for ( var i=0,n=fields.length; i<n; i++ ){
       var field  = fields[i],
           errors = form_errors[field],
           $field = $form.find('input[name=' + field + ']');

       $field.applyErrorMarkup(errors);    // whatever you plan to do with the field
    }
});



// Pseudocode of one possible way to validate your form
function validateForm(frm){
   var errors = {};

   // BEGIN LOOP: <insert code to iterate over fields and validity checks>
   var field = 'fieldname';            // placeholder

   if( true /* error found */ ){
      var err = errors[field];
      var msg = 'new error message';   // should be the dynamic validity check error message (e.g., 'only numbers permitted')
      errors[field] = err && [msg].concat( err ) || msg;
   }
   // END LOOP

   return errors;
}
```